# DatabaseError at /admin/app1/book/ no such column: app1_book.related_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wrote a Django Program for admin. But it turns out the ForeignKey has something wrong, which I can't find out.

Here is my admin.py and views.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app1.models import *

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','auther','pages')
    search_fields = ['name']

admin.site.register(Book,BookAdmin)
admin.site.register(RelatedBook)
```

views.py:

```
from django.db import models
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('s','Science'),
    ('l','Literature'),
    ('e','else'),

)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    auther = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    related = models.ForeignKey('RelatedBook')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

class RelatedBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you added the related column after you first created the `Book` model, then syncdb will not create it, since it does not handle migrations.

If you have important data, then you'll need to add the column manually. How you do this depends on which database you are using.

If you don't have any data you need to keep, then dropping the Book table and re-running syncb is probably easiest.

Schema migrations will be part of the upcoming Django 1.7 release. For Django 1.6 and earlier, you may want to explore the migrations tool [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) in future.